# RESTful service using visual studio

Tags: c#, rest

I have a very simple RESTful api that i want to make using visual studio.
I have followed a guide but i am getting an error.

Here is how my files are organized:

[image]

Here is the content of service.svc:

```
    <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" CodeBehind="~/Service.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"%>
```

And the error i am getting:

> The type 'Service', provided as the Service attribute value in the
>   ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by joining Iservice and Service to one file and added to correct namspace

Comment: Do not place your interface and implementation in the same file, the entire purpose of having a separate interface is that it is independent of the implementation. Install Resharper and it'll help you with namespaces and usings which seems to be missing here.